# Convert dataframe array type column to string without losing element names/schema

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

In my dataframe, I need to convert an array type column to string without losing the element names/schema for the data in the column.

My dataframe schema:

```
root
 |-- accountId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- documents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- accountId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- agreementId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- obligations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- resourceVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updatedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updatedDate: string (nullable = true)
```

Dataframe sample data (I am showing it in JSON format, but it's columns in Spark dataframe):

```json
{
    "accountId":"1",
    "documents":{
        "list":[{
            "element":{
                "accountId":"1",
                "agreementId":"1.2",
                "createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z",
                "externalId":"16",
                "id":"123",
                "name":"test1.docx",
                "obligations":{},
                "resourceVersion":1,
                "updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"
            }
        }]
    }
}
{
    "accountId":"2",
    "documents":{
        "list":[{
            "element":{
                "accountId":"2",
                "agreementId":"2.2",
                "createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z",
                "externalId":"18",
                "id":"123",
                "name":"test2.docx",
                "obligations":{},
                "resourceVersion":1,
                "updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

My current code:

```py
df_string = df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])
```

What it can do (column names disappear in documents):

```json
{
    "accountId":"1",
    "documents":[{"1","1.2","2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","16",:"123","test1.docx","",1,"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]
}
{
    "accountId":"2",
    "documents":[{"2","2.2","2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","18","123","test2.docx","","1","2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]
}
```

What I need to accomplish (column names must remain in documents):

```json
{
    "accountId":"1",
    "documents":[{"accountId":"1","agreementId":"1.2","createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","externalId":"16","id":"123","name":"test1.docx","obligations":"","resourceVersion":"1","updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]
}
{
    "accountId":"2",
    "documents":[{"accountId":"2","agreementId":"2.2","createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","externalId":"18","id":"123","name":"test2.docx","obligations":"","resourceVersion":"1","updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]
}
```

Comment: An array is a premitive data type that's basically a container. In your current schema, the array carries a stuct which again is a container. A string on the other hand is a flat datatype and cannot be storied or made to nest another dataformat. You may be meaning something else. If that's the case, that's fine... just give us the what you expect as a new schema

Comment: Thank you for your comment @wwnde. "You may be meaning something else. If that's the case, that's fine... just give us the what you expect as a new schema": documents attribute needs to become a string data type containing the result as shown above in "What I need to accomplish". As you can see above, currently I am loosing the attribute names inside documents after it is converted to string. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) could be your answer. It transforms a complex type column (structs, arrays, maps) into a JSON string.

Input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1", [("1", "1.2", "Tom", "2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z", "123", [""], 1, "Tom", "2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z")]),
     ("2", [("2", "2.2", "Tim", "2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z", "123", [""], 1, "Tim", "2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z")])],
    'accountId:string,documents:array<struct<accountId:string,agreementId:string,createdBy:string,createdDate:string,id:string,obligations:array<string>,resourceVersion:bigint,updatedBy:string,updatedDate:string>>')
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- accountId: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- documents: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- accountId: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- agreementId: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- createdDate: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- obligations: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- resourceVersion: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- updatedBy: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- updatedDate: string (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn("documents", F.to_json("documents"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |accountId|documents                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
# +---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |1        |[{"accountId":"1","agreementId":"1.2","createdBy":"Tom","createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","id":"123","obligations":[""],"resourceVersion":1,"updatedBy":"Tom","updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]|
# |2        |[{"accountId":"2","agreementId":"2.2","createdBy":"Tim","createdDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.539646Z","id":"123","obligations":[""],"resourceVersion":1,"updatedBy":"Tim","updatedDate":"2022-10-06T19:33:42.680233Z"}]|
# +---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- accountId: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- documents: string (nullable = true)
```